# Threatened to be sent home without pay due to slow work day by company with military contract

Tags: salary

I work for a company that has a military contract and they often threaten us with the fact that we aren't guaranteed a 40 hour work week and that they can send us home early without pay if they want. Does the company lose money or have to pay the military back that money if we are sent home?  Or does the company just keep them money they we would have gotten paid if we had stayed?  Isn't the company paid in advance for the employees it is contracted to have working for them or how does it work exactly?  They keep threatening to do it but have yet to follow through with it.

Comment: Nobody on The Workplace has any information on the contract that your employer has, so any answer would be nothing but a guess.

Comment: This _is_ one of the hazards of working hourly without a contract that specifies number of hours. The restaurant biz is notorious for scrambling work schedules at whim, for example.

Comment: Are you hourly or salaried?

Comment: We are all hourly employees and since my posting I have found out the answer to my inquiry through my union reps.  It seems that the company would lose money for those hours we don't wok since the government doesn't pay for contracted hours not worked.  So in essence the company has been threatening us with something they have no intention of following through with.  If we were working directly for the company that directly pays our salary then things may be different.  But since the contract was based upon the actual hours that we are contracted for,  they get paid when we get paid...lol

Comment: In that case, this sounds more like an observation/heads-up than a threat. Though it could still be one, depending on what they seem to think you are supposed to do about it. –

Answer (score 11):

No one here can say what's in the contract between your company and the military  - but it isn't really relevant. What matters is the contract between your company and *you*.

So you need to review that contract (ideally with your union rep if you have one), and also the laws wherever you live to see whether they're actually able to send you home without pay, and if so, how much notice they have to give you.

Answer (score 3):

Government contracts can take several forms:

- They charge a fixed price each month no matter how many hours are worked.
- They can only bill based on the number of hours worked.

The contracts can also have minimum  and maximum number of people hours each period.

Not paying you on a slow day, increases their profits on a fixed price contract. Not paying you on a time and materials contract misses the opportunity from profiting on those hours.

In addition there can be a contract between you and the company regarding minimum hours each week.

A complexity regarding the specific government contract can be a ceiling on the contract. The more people working on the contract the sooner the money runs out. Sometimes if the contract is running hot, they ask people to take vacation hours to extend the time before the money runs out. I have been on a contract that would run out of money unless everybody took 3 weeks of PTO each yer.

Comment: Emphasis on the "increases their profits" part - that's exactly what this is, and a scummy move at that. If the company was billing the government for hours worked, then they would be making money on more hours. The company is just trying to squeeze every penny out of this contract at the cost of its reputation and employee goodwill.

Comment: At the end of the day, the contractor cannot allow an individual to bill hours to a project, if they are not actively working that project. If the government performs an audit on whom worked on the project, and the progress of the project does match the hours being worked on the project, they open themselves to the government making formal complaints to the contracting office. While you can be salaried as a employee of a defense contractor, if there isn’t  a charge code you can bill to, the defense contractor can’t allow you to charge to anything unless your activity working that activity.

Comment: @JackGifford - I work in this world. If the project is running behind, and the end of the contract is to far out, it’s justified to slow the burn on the hours to only the essential employees. I was on the other end of a project (accepting the end product), the project ran out of money 3 months before deployment, everyone that was working on it was taken off and only the essential employee was left on.  Even then a contract extension and additional money was required to finish the project. Project will still after those adjustments require another POP expansion.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your employment contract with your company and the contract between your company and the government.

When I worked in the defense industry, I had to record hours worked against specific activities. Some were related to contracts, while others were not. Since I was a salaried employee, I needed to record at least 40 hours per week. Generally, I was expected to be working on something - if not a contract, internal training, skills development for upcoming/future work, or some other approved type of work, otherwise record paid time off. Some contracts allowed for overtime, so I could record 40+ hours and get paid for those additional hours. The contract between your company and the government specifies what activities the government will pay for, how much time can be spent on those activities, and when the work can happen. This contract would also say what happens if your company delivers faster than anticipated, with less hours, or by spending less money.

However, you may not be a salaried employee. This would be in the contract with your company. If you're an hourly employee, then your company may very well be able to reduce your hours and not pay you for them if they don't have contracts in place. This could mean that they can tell you to not record work against the contract if they don't think it's in the best interests of the project to have you working on it. This is often up to the project manager to make sure that the project is spending its allocated resources effectively, within the scope of the contract with the customer, which could mean telling people to hold off on work until a more appropriate time.